# Why can't operator!= do the conversion?

Tags: c++

I have following code with error:

> (Visual Studio error:)Error   5   error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type '` Node' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

```
  template <class C, class T>
    C find2 ( C first , C last, T c )
    {
        //
        while ( first != last && *first != c )
        {
            ++first;
        }

        return first;
    }

    struct Node
    {
        Node(int a ,Node* b):val(a),next(b){};
        int val;
        Node* next;
    };

    template <class T>
    struct node_wrap
    {
        T* ptr;

        node_wrap ( T* p = 0 ) : ptr ( p ) {}
        Node& operator*() const {return *ptr;}
        Node* operator->() const {return ptr;}
        node_wrap& operator++ () {ptr = ptr->next; return * this;}
        node_wrap operator++ ( int ) {node_wrap tmp = *this; ++*this; return tmp;}

        bool operator== ( const node_wrap& i ) const {return ptr == i.ptr;}
        bool operator!= ( const node_wrap& i ) const {return ptr != i.ptr;}

    };
    bool operator== ( const Node& node, int n )
    {
        return node.val == n;
    }


    int main()
    {

        Node* node1=new Node(3,NULL);
        Node* node2=new Node(4,NULL);
        node1->next = node2;
        find2 ( node_wrap<Node>(node1), node_wrap<Node>(), 3) ) ;
        delete node1;
        delete node2;
        return 0;
    }
```

what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Are you trying to duplicate what `std::list` and `std::find` already do for you? :)

Comment: No~ I just wanna try something out from book <<Generic Programming and the STL >>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to compare a `Node` with an `int` (this is done in the function `find2` when performing `*first != c`).

While you have provided an `operator==` for comparing a `Node` with an `int`, you haven't provided an `operator!=` to do the same. If you add one, this should work.

Comment: what interjay says: define `bool operator!= ( const Node& node, int n )` in terms of the operator==() you already have.

Answer (score 3):

`Iterator` is of type `node_wrap<Node>`, so `*first` returns a `Node` here:

```
    while ( first != last && *first != c )
```

which has no `!=` operator that compares it to the type of `c`, which is `int`. You probably meant:

```
    while ( first != last && first->val != c )
```

I'd recommend this over the other approach of defining `operator==` and `operator!=` that compare `Node` to `int`, because these are fundamentally different types and should not be comparable to one another.

Comment: Iterator is a typename in template function.

Comment: I am doing just a test.~ I won`t do it in real project.and thank  you anyway~